# Issues in generating gabor wavelets

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I am having some issues in generating the gabor wavelets. I was referring to this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.6259&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and they are generating wavelets like this

[image]

I used this package available at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35106-the-phd-face-recognition-toolbox to generate the Gabor wavelets

However I only get the wavelets like this

[image]

which is different than what is shown in the paper. How can I achieve similar gabor wavelets.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable variant is that you have set too high frequency, try to lower it.
I reccomend to take a look on this code which does what you need:
http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/#phasecong

And explanation how does it work
http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/PhaseCongruency/Docs/convexpl.html